# Usage of prepositions after the noun "support"

Tags: prepositions

1. You have been a great support **to** my mom.
2. You have been a great support **of** my mom.
3. You have been a great support **for** my mom.

Do all prepositions work here? The first one is correct as it's the original example from a dictionary, but I am wondering if the other two prepositions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1    You have been a great support to my mom.

This is fine. It sounds like the person has actively supported your mom.

> 2    You have been a great support of my mom.

This is not quite correct. You can say someone is a *supporter of* someone or something, but this normally means that they are *championing* them, or are a 'fan' of them rather than helping them.

> 3    You have been a great support for my mom.

This is also fine. The difference to option 1 is that this could be taken to mean the person was supportive of your mom *when required*. When someone is "there for" someone else it means they are *willing* to be supportive, if needed.

Comment: Great answer :-). May I ask if it is grammatically correct to use the indefinite article in "**a** great support" in Example 3?

Comment: @AydenFerguson Yes, you should say they were "a support", because you are using support as a noun. You could say they were "supportive" if you dont want an article.